# Generating files/folders?

Tags: php, file-io

This might be a horrifically stupid question, but how would I go about doing this in PHP:

I'd like to make a .zip file dynamically, then serve it as a download immediately with force-download mime or something, with the contents of `$string`, with a folder structure.

Premade folder structure `license\keys\{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\{$fn}.cf` and `{$fn}.cf` would contain the contents of `$string`, inside the .zip file

I have literally no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`ZipArchive` class](http://www.php.net/ziparchive). Use it to create a temporary `ZIP` file, close the `ZipArchive`, stream the temporary `ZIP` file to the user, and delete the temporary `ZIP`.

Comment: $za->open('theZip.zip'); Any idea if this can dynamically spit one out without having to save it?

Comment: @jmoon: You may be able to use [`php://output`](http://www.php.net/wrappers.php), but `ZipArchive` might want a readable/seekable stream.

Comment: going to take a look at this now, at worst i can just use /tmp/[sha512 hash of content file].zip